# Prepared statements cassandra-stress tool

Tags: cassandra, benchmarking, cassandra-2.0, stress-testing, cassandra-stress

I would like to know if it's possible to have the `cassandra-stress tool` to run a predefined set of queries instead of random reads.

For example, lets say I have keyspace `BENCHMARK` with a `LOGS` table

```
CREATE TABLE LOGS(log_id int PRIMARY KEY, log_date timestamp,
log_severity text, log_text text);
```

The data in this table is loaded from a `CSV` file and not using the stress tool

Now I would like to run `cassandra-stress` with a set of predefined queries like

`SELECT * FROM LOGS WHERE log_severity="WARN";`

I saw that the tool has a `--use-prepared-statements` options but I don't know how to use this.

Could someone provide some insight on this?

I'm using Cassandra 2.0.6

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe `cassandra-stress` doesn't support execution of arbitrary queries.  You can use something like http://mishail.github.io/CqlJmeter/, but that plugin doesn't support the prepared statements.

Comment: I see this is a plugin for JMeter. I will look into it if I can confirm that cassandra-stress does not support arbitrary queries. Thanks!